# Genson Caching of Bean Accessors

Tags: java, json, caching, genson

I have recently upgraded to Genson 1.3 and I am not 100% sure if this issue is new or not as previously I patched the 0.98 version to make it work.

**Context**

We are using our own implementation of the BeanMutatorAccessorResolver. This is so that we can dynamically decide whether a property should be serialized or not. Basically we have integrated Genson into our generic jersey REST API interface. Genson does all the serializing and deserializing. When doing a GET requests it is possible for a user to pass fields in the URL in order to filter those he specifically needs (especially for large objects this is necessary where you only need 3 fields or so for displaying a table overview). For example: ?fields=field1, field2, field3. We then know in our implementation of BeanMutatorAccessorResolver exactly which fields to serialize and which ones to ignore. This is mainly intended for speeding up requests and parsing as we are then working with less data.

**Problem**

Unfortunately it seems that once Genson has read in all the fields via reflection or whatever, it caches that. This would be no problem if we were always requesting the same fields. Unfortunately on some occasions we need more fields then before, but because Genson does not visit our BeanMutatorAccessorResolver a second time it only returns the few fields that it has already cached.

Is there anyway around this? Perhaps there is a better solution than turning cahing off completely - because that would most probably hurt performance, right?

**Update**

Is seems that I have found the location where this is happening. Basically Genson returns a cached converter in Genson.provideConverter(Type forType) (line: 154).

```
Converter<T> converter = (Converter<T>) converterCache.get(forType);
```

At the top of the method I have noticed that it looks for a __GENSON$DO_NOT_CACHE_CONVERTER.

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(ThreadLocalHolder.get("__GENSON$DO_NOT_CACHE_CONVERTER", Boolean.class))) {
```

Should I perhaps set this value or is there a better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately adding the line "ThreadLocalHolder.store("__GENSON$DO_NOT_CACHE_CONVERTER", true);" to my Jersey Resource class does not seem to help either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved thanks to Eugen. The solution can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genson/Z1oFHJfA-5w.

Basically you need to extend 3 classes to get this working:

1. GensonBundle, which you can register with the GensonBuilder.
2. BaseBeanDescriptorProvider, which gets created in GensonBundle.
3. BeanDescriptor, which gets created in BaseBeanDescriptorProvider and
   which contains the serialize method to adapt to your needs.